# Android open pdf from asset folder

Tags: android, kotlin

How to open pdf Files from asset folder? I don't want to copy it to some other directory.
Add mypdf.pdf to asset directory and open it with file:///android_asset/mypdf.pdf results in exposed beyond app through Intent.getData() error.

```
val file = File("file:///android_asset/" + fileName)

val pdfIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
pdfIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf")
pdfIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP;
startActivity(pdfIntent)
```

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: First, `file:///android_asset/` is for internal use within an app, specifically with `WebView`. It has no meaning elsewhere. Second, [`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/Intent#action_open_document) does not take a `Uri` as input in the "data" facet (`setData()` or `setDataAndType()`). While you can provide a `Uri` in `EXTRA_INITIAL_URI`, that would have to be for some past document that you created or opened, not for a file and not for an asset. What exactly do you mean by "open pdf Files"?

Comment: "open pdf files" =  Users should be able to open and read instruction manuals. I added 7 pdf to asset folder. Do I really  have to copy them to cache-path or files-path to open  inside webview or pdf viewer? On iOS I simply use UIDocumentInteractionController to open pdf.
       guard let urlFile = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: "pdf") else { return }
       documentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController.init(url: urlFile)
        documentInteractionController?.delegate = self
      documentInteractionController?.presentPreview(animated: true)